# Is it possible to lower the encryption level to avoid the error: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key

Tags: java, spring, encryption

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;

public class EncryptorTest {

  @Test
  public void testEncryption() {
    TextEncryptor te = Encryptors.text("password", "abcdef");
    te.encrypt("Hello World!");
  }

}
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to initialize due to invalid secret key
```

It seems that I have to download some policy file JCE extension to get this to work: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

I want to avoid this added dependency during deployment, and honestly I don't need 256 bit encryption for this.

Is it possible to lower the level to something that works w/o having to download this JCE extension?

Comment: There does not seem to be an option for this; looking at the API it is 256 bit or the highway. I'm not a huge fan of these kind of wrappers, you could mimic the API relatively easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the value 256 is hard coded into the source:

```
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), Hex.decode(salt), 1024, 256);
```

This can be found in [`AesBytesEncryptor`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/rb3.2.5.RELEASE/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/encrypt/AesBytesEncryptor.java) on line 54 at least up to release 3.2.5.

Note that Spring uses the Apache license, so there is nothing stopping you from creating your own implementation that uses 128 as constant.

Comment: Is that the main class I could just copy and paste and then change 256 to 128?

Comment: Yes, that sure seems to be a good option - altered answer. One important thing to note: no integrity or authentication (e.g. a HMAC) is added by the wrapper classes, and you should not use the CBC mode of operation within a transport protocol (i.e. where padding oracles apply). Adding a HMAC over the ciphertext *and* IV would significantly heighten the security.

Comment: one question, when a user authenticates, do I hash the users password using the same salt value and then compare with the hash in the db, or do I decrypt the password in the db and compare it with the attempt?

Comment: Usually you simply compare the hash, but decryption would amount to the same thing, when performed properly. You could use decryption or - even better - an additional key derivation if you want to use the password for different purposes, but usually the hash is simply compared.

Comment: Interesting, the Hash result is different even when I use the same salt value.  So I have to decrypt the users's password hash in the db and compare it with the password attempt in plain text.